# Flutter Row ignore children if it overflows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to calculate or ignore the Children widgets of Row if it gets overflow. I dont want to use Wrap to put the content to the next line, I want to hide the overflowing child widgets

```
Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: searchResult.serviceNames
                      .map((service) => getServiceLabels(service))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
```

**P.S a way to Clip the overflowing Wrap children is what Im after**

Comment: See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wrap the child to next line, you can put the overflowing widget within a `SingleChildScrollView` that allows the `Row` in this case to expand to its outer boundary without overflowing:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
        child: Row(
                  children: searchResult.serviceNames
                      .map((service) => getServiceLabels(service))
                      .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

In reality, if you want to display each item wholely (meaning without being cut off in the middle because of lack of screen width), based on screen size you have 2 options:

- Calculate the width of each item:

```dart
var itemWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).width // 3; // 3 is number of items you want to display
```

- Calculate the number of items:

```dart
var itemNumbers = MediaQuery.of(context).width // 150; // 150 is the item's width you want to display
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Bach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10488444/bach) said, you can wrap the content in a `SingleChildScrollView`. However, if you want to restrict the content from scrolling, you can add `NeverScrollablePhysics`:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [],
          ),
        );
```